# 404 not found when trying to use .htaccess

Tags: apache2

Im trying to configure a software called NamelessMC and it requires a .htaccess. The instructions it gave me was to add the following to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

But it keeps giving me the same error "The requested URL /install was not found on this server." Which to "fix" that, you needed to enable .htaccess which that code should. Any help would be great.

Comment: What are the full contents of that `sites-available/default` file - in particular, the whole `<VirtualHost>` section so we can see its `DocumentRoot`, any other `<Directory>` sections or aliases?  What is in `/var/www/install`?

Comment: Thats whats weird, It doesn't have anything else in it.

Comment: Look for a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` which has a `Directory` entry similar to your post and make sure the `AllowOverride` line is changed to `All`.

Comment: Which version of Apache do you have?  Is it the version from Ubuntu?  You should have already had a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file, which should contain a lot of existing settings, most of them inside a `<VirtualHost>` section.  It would have had an existing `<Directory>` section inside it, which you could had modified to suit.

Comment: All that said, it sounds like the instructions NamelessMC is giving are a bit suspect, because if you follow them you're changing the *default* virtual host on Apache and you're using the *root* of `/var/www` - this won't be a good idea if you host multiple sites on Apache already.